# How to remove left side shadow from React Burger Menu?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm

I have React Burger Menu setup and it work perfectly. The only issue is the shadow on left side. You can see the in the screenshot attached.

[image]

```
<div id="" className="bm-menu-wrap" style="position: fixed; right: inherit; z-index: 1100; width: 300px; height: 100%; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; transform: translate3d(-100%, 0px, 0px);">
.....
.....
.....
</div>
```

The code is look like above where the translate3d is

> translate3d(-100%, 0px, 0px);

If I change it to

> translate3d(-110%, 0px, 0px);

Then it will not show the shadow, unfortunately I can not do that with CSS. As there is any possibility to do it without effecting the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I did add the css to .bm-menu

```
.bm-menu {
    background: #373a47;
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

After adding transform:

> matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

the problem get solved.